# Handling Average of a lot of Values

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, leaflet.markercluster

I'm inserting Markers with a specific Value onto an Openstreetmap via leaflet. Futhermore I want those Markers to get Clusterd while zooming out of the map. The Clustericon should show the average Value of the Cluster. 
This far, there is no Problem. I iterate over all Markers in each Cluster, add the values together and then divide by the amount of Markers. Then I create a custom Icon wich is colored depending on the Value and has a Label with the average Value. This works great for small amounts of Markers. The Problem is, that I have to insert a LOT of Markers in the nothern Area of Germany. I mean like at least 50000.

In this Case the Browser isn't able to load the page. But if I set the default zoom to 18 it does load the page. And there are no Problems while zooming out of the page. I paste my Code below:

```js
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
  chunkedLoading: true, 
  chunkProgress: updateProgressBar,
  showCoverageOnHover: false,
  maxClusterRadius: 100,
  iconCreateFunction : function(cluster) {
   var val = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < cluster.getAllChildMarkers().length; i++) {
    val = val
      + parseInt(cluster.getAllChildMarkers()[i].options.speed)
   } 
   var avg = val / cluster.getAllChildMarkers().length;
   avg = Math.round(avg * 10) / 10;
     
   
   return new L.divIcon({
    html: "<div style='background-color: " + generateColor(avg) + "'><span>" + avg + "</span></div>",
    className: ' marker-cluster',
    iconSize: new L.point(40, 40)
   })
  }
 });
```

Now I need a solution to make this map functional.

Comment: i would save the result from `cluster.getAllChildMarkers()` into a local variable (don't know if its a really expensive function call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what is your bottleneck without a proper case reproduction.

You could at least start by caching your markers array:

```js
function iconCreateFunction(cluster) {
    var val = 0,
        childMarkers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers(), // Store in local variable to avoid having to execute it many times.
        total = childMarkers.length;

    for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        val = val + parseInt(childMarkers[i].options.speed)
    } 
    var avg = val / total;
    avg = Math.round(avg * 10) / 10;


    return new L.divIcon({
        html: "<div style='background-color: " + generateColor(avg) + "'><span>" + avg + "</span></div>",
        className: ' marker-cluster',
        iconSize: new L.point(40, 40)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that made it at leat a little bit faster. I think I have to go with a solution where I just load some of the Datapoint into to map or something. Like you have to preselect the Region you wanna see